# Ruby: Loop through hash and check if a key exists to determine markup and data to be displayed

Tags: ruby, haml

This is my first time working with Ruby, so I may be approaching this incorrectly.

I am trying to go through a hash to display it's contents. As I'm going through the hash I'll need to test if a key exists, like city. If city doesn't exist then it shouldn't display the address. This is where I've started with building my hash:

```
# app.rb
set :haml, :format => :html5
get "/" do
    @users = Hash[
                  [["name", "bill"], ["city", "nyc"],  ["address", "street"]],
                  [["name", "ted"], ["city", "denver"]],
                  [["name", "sam"], ["address", "road"]]
                 ]
    haml :index
end
```

And this is how I am looping through the hash:

```
# layout.haml
- @users.each do |user|
    - user.each do |u|
        - u.each do |b|
            = b
```

Once I get to b it will display all of the content like so:

```
["name", "bill"]
["city", "nyc"]
["address", "street"]
["name", "ted"]
["city", "denver"]
```

In the loop, how can I display the name as well as check to see if the address exists for each user to determine if the city should be displayed as well as any markup that may need to be added? It would ideally display something like:

```
<p>bill, <span class="address">nyc, street</span></p>
<p>ted</p>
<p>sam, <span class="address">road</span></p>
```

Am I creating the Hash properly to do it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of what you are trying to do with nested *arrays* inside a hash, it would be better to have an array that contains `user` hashes:

```
@users = [
           { :name => 'bill', :city => 'city', :address => 'street' },
           { :name => 'ted', :city => 'denver' },
           { :name => 'sam', :address => 'road' }
         ]
```

With that, you can do something like this:

```
- @users.each do |user|
    = user[:name]
    - if user.has_key?(:address) && user.has_key?(:city)
        = "#{user[:address]}, #{user[:city]}"
    - elsif user.has_key?(:address)
        = "#{user[:address]}"
```

Comment: I had to make one fix to this. on line 3 the last has_key should be `(:city)` and not `[:city]` Thanks for the help, does exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake, fixed it.